# Reorder div columns at screen/window resize

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

I have two columns within an article, one contains a slideshow and the other text, they sit alongside each other but not always at the same side. What I want to do is when the screen/window size dips to lets say ipad size I'd like the slideshow container to sit at the top, and the text at the bottom to take advantage of the screen size. Each of the pages has a different order of divs, so not quite as simple as using float:....  I read another question on here that went someway to answer the question, but not with screen/window size.

HTML:

```
<article>
<div class="column-1">
   text Content
</div>
<div class="column-2">
    slide Content
</div>
</article>
```

JS

```
$('.column-2').insertBefore('.column-1');
```

desired effect:

window  width < 768

column-2  **Top**

column-1   **Bottom**

I cobbled together this, but as usual it doesn't function.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if ( $(window).width() < 768 ){
        $('.column-1').before($('.column-2'));
        }else{
        $('.column-2').before($('.column-1'));
         }
    });
```

Can anyone help, it would be greatly appreciated. It's not reading the window width when the window is resized to below 768px and reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ( $(window).width() < 768 ){
        $('.column-1').before($('.column-2'));
    }

    $(window).resize(function(){
        if ( $(window).width() < 768 ){
            $('.column-1').before($('.column-2'));
        }else{
            $('.column-2').before($('.column-1'));
        }
    });
});
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/ft92ba9q/3/

Comment: That does and doesn't work. I mistakenly placed the resize function in, and that's not working the way that it should. The divs should only reorder when the window size falls below > 768 and only then. Thanks for replying though.

Comment: Nope, sorry that still doesn't work it's not reordering at all.

Comment: It is yes, but only when it's  resized. It's reordering as soon as the resize takes place, not initially when the page loads at > 768px. It needs to be reordered when the document loads not when it's resized.

Comment: I don't know what you want then. I clean the answer and the comments, good look anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using FlexBox? No JavaScript or jQuery required.

You can [view this example on CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdNbbY)

HTML:

```
<main>
  <article>
    First
  </article>

  <aside>
    Second
  </aside>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
main {
  -webkit-display: flex;
  display: flex;

  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

/* Tablet and mobile */
@media only screen and (max-width : 1024px) {
  article {
    -webkit-order: 1;
    order: 1;
  }

  aside {
    -webkit-order: 2;
    order: 2;
  }
}

/* Desktop */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1025px) {
  article {
    -webkit-order: 2;
    order: 2;
  }

  aside {
    -webkit-order: 1;
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks bashaus,  but I'm confused enough already without adding yet another thing ha,ha :)

Comment: @RossAnderson This is a complete solution using CSS only (you don't need any JavaScript). It's also probably the easiest solution. You can use CSS to reorder items using the order property. Check out the documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order